# Free software for minimal post-processing requirements

Tags: post-processing, raw, software-recommendation

I wanted to ask for a recommendation for a free post-processing software.
As I am primarily a jpeg shooter - who keeps the raw files "just in case" - my requirements are quite minimal:

- cropping
- rotating
- converting to B&W
- changes to white balance, saturation, exposure
- ability to work with RAW files from Leica M9, Fuji X-Pro2, Ricoh GR and GR iii
- works on Windows

> Would you be able to recommend such a software? In this forum I have seen mention of "Darktable" and "RawTherapee". But I was not sure whether they meet these requirements, especially around the RAW file formats.

Comment: Hi Claus and welcome to Photo.SE! This site is a bit different from other forums in that it best works when you have a specific question, that you've looked into (briefly) and that can have answers that do not become outdated very fast (feel free to take the [tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is quite broad: there is a myriad of applications that can do what you want. Besides that, the answer would become outdated as products come and go.

Comment: Try the software recommendations SE site.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke ah ok I understand - I thought my question would be a good fit. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @EricS That's a good idea, let me follow up on this!

Comment: Bot DT and RT will do. On [Pixls.us](https://discuss.pixls.us/) you can discuss with other users, and with the authors.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks a lot for your advice! I will take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a non-destructive editor such as Darktable.

It will provide the same general workflow for both jpg and RAW and because manipulations are saved as commands, non-destructive editors have the least degradation for jpgs. Degradation only happens on final export not at intermediate steps.

Or to put it another way, a non-destructive editor treats your originals as negatives. A jpg original is simply a less information dense negative than a raw (like 135 v 120 film maybe).